# Load data from BigQuery to Neo4J database

Tags: python, google-bigquery, neo4j, google-cloud-storage

I am new to Neo4J graph database, and need some references to articles or videos to help me load data from [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) to Neo4J.

If someone has already done this, please guide me through the process.

Thanks

Comment: Will this help? https://neo4j.com/blog/loading-data-neo4j-google-cloud-dataflow/
I haven't tried though.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this as a reference to your [use case](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/transform-publicly-available-bigquery-data-and-stackdriver-logs-into-graph-databases-with-neo4j) and possibly help you in your inquiry, The blog introduces how to load a BQ data to neo4j.

> Transform publicly available BigQuery data and Stackdriver logs into graph databases with Neo4j